# Test for e. coli in murky water

Tags: ecoli

We had some tests done on some stream water. In the results report, the lab said:

The coliform/e. coli test was requested and [we] attempted to test for the bacteria but the sample was too dark in color to run the test, therefore, a result for coliform/e.coli is not available. This test requires a sample with little or no sample color to successfully read the color change that is performed during the test.

The test method is [SM 9223B](https://www.nemi.gov/methods/method_summary/5583/)

Is there an e. coli test that can be done on murky water?